# multithreading while blocking main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

How do I start 2 or more threads all at once and block the main thread until the others threads are complete?

Comment: Threading in C# for the question above

Answer (score 12):

From the main thread, call [`Thread.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) on each of the other threads.

(EDIT: Now you've specified C#, there's no need for the platform agnostic comment.)

For example:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(FirstMethod).Start();
Thread t2 = new Thread(SecondMethod).Start();

t1.Join();
t2.Join();
```

It doesn't matter what order you call `Join` in, if you only want to wait until they've *all* finished. (If you want to continue when *any* of them have finished, you need to get into the realm of wait handles.)

Comment: In .NET 4.0 you may also get value out of using a System.Threading.CountdownEvent and calling 'Signal' on the child threads and 'Wait' on the main thread, or System.Threading.Barrier and call SignalAndWait on all three threads.

Answer (score 2):

```
public delegate void AsyncTask(object state);

public void Method1(object state) .....

public void Method2(object state) .....


public void RunAsyncAndWait(){

   AsyncTask ac1 = new AsyncTask(Method1);
   AsyncTask ac2 = new AsyncTask(Method2);

   WaitHandle[] waits = new WaitHandle[2];

   IAsyncResult r1 = ac1.BeginInvoke( someData , null , null );
   IAsyncResult r2 = ac2.BeginInvoke( someData , null , null );

   waits[0] = r1.AsyncWaitHandle;
   waits[1] = r2.AsyncWaitHandle;

   WaitHandle.WaitAll(waits);

}
```

This works, some people will aruge that if any of thread finishes first it will wait endlessly but I have tried, it have worked always. You can also give timeout to wait for. And in BeginInvoke first parameter is the value passed inside your methods.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example of how to do threading in C# on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(VS.71).aspx#vcwlkthreadingtutorialexample1creating

If you look at the Mutex example it demonstrates putting the main thread to sleep until all child threads have completed.

Answer (score 0):

Jeffry Richter of Wintellect has a [library for download](http://www.wintellect.com/PowerThreading.aspx) called the Power Threading library.  I have not used it myself but it might be helpful.